# Using "it" as dummy pronoun

Tags: translation, expletive-pronoun

When I translate an Italian sentence, I often use the "dummy it" to keep the same structure of the Italian sentence.
For example, translating *è stato difficile trovare il colpevole*, I would say "it has been difficult to find who is guilty" instead of "finding who is guilty has been difficult" or "to find who is guilty has been difficult." The Italian equivalent of the last sentence is *trovare il colpevole è stato difficile*, which is not different from *è stato difficile trovare il colpevole*. The only difference is that I inverted the order of *trovare il colpevole*, and *è stato difficile*, and I am probably highlighting the fact it has been difficult.

In  this case, using *it* has a purpose. Imagine speaking with somebody that uses a sentence similar to the one I used as example every time a new topic is introduced.
Can using a sentence with the same structure of the sentence I used as example be seen as overusing a construct, such as in the case I would keep saying *this very moment* instead of *this moment*, or "I do like it" instead of "I like it"?

Comment: A minor note about your first example sentence: It's much more common (and natural) to use "find out" than just "find when talking about discovering a previously unknown fact: "It has been difficult to find out who is guilty."

Comment: I don't speak Italian, buy I'm wondering if "find the guilty PERSON" or "find the guilty ONE" might be more apt than "find out who is guilty".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't really say if you're "overusing" the dummy **it** from a single example. But I think **it's** highly unlikely, because **it's** such a standard feature of English.

Firstly, notice that in the previous sentence, I've used a second pronoun **it** to reference the initial dummy **it**. There's nothing unusual about that; we use dummy **it** all over the place.

Secondly, I'd suggest OP's other habits (*"this **very** moment", "I **do** like it"*) aren't really comparable, because they're both *emphatic* forms. A native speaker is bound to notice if you keep emphasising everything you say, but they're not going to notice if you just happen to use dummy **it** a lot.

---

EDIT: I can't resist pointing out that in my final sentence above, I could quite reasonably have written *"...they're not going to notice **it** if you just happen to..."*. And adding a useful link [describing/explaining the dummy "it" and related sentence structures.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5VNtAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&dq=grammar%20%22dummy%20it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LYEFVYL7DMqI7AbA7YCgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22dummy%20it%22&f=false)

Comment: Notice that in the phrase I used as example, _it_ is at the beginning of the sentence, and it doesn't follow words like _because_. The difference is that I could rewrite my example as "Finding who was guilty has been difficult."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's irrelevant whether **it** comes at the beginning of the sentence. My example second sentence could just as easily have been simply *"**It's** highly unlikely because it's such a standard feature of English."* Also note that my first sentence could have said *"we can't really say if **the usage** is excessive"*. In which case someone *might* say my second "it" in the second sentence isn't a "dummy", because it's a pronoun indicating ***the usage***. But that would be nitpicking (like I said, ***it's*** common).

Comment: Yet, my question is not about generally using _it_ as expletive pronoun. I know that "it is raining" cannot be rephrased as "the sky is raining," and that "I think it is correct" would become longer, if I rephrase it without _it_.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "expletive pronoun". I'm just saying that sometimes it's not clear-cut as to whether any given usage of "it" definitely has an "identifiable" referent or not. But it doesn't really make much difference anyway - all that matters is in English we can use "it" when it's impossible to say exactly what it refers to (it might interest you to try and figure out what every different instance of "it" refers to in this sentence, for example). But if you can't name a referent, just call it "dummy it".

Comment: *Expletive pronoun* is a term-of-art equivalent to *dummy pronoun*.

Comment: @StoneyB: In that case I'm totally lost. The question cites *"it has been difficult to find who is guilty"* as an example of the type of construction OP is worried he might be overusing, but I don't know how to interpret that example as anything other than an instance of "dummy it". If OP thinks it's *not*, I don't see what he's getting at.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  No, I think he's worried about overusing it because his language doesn't require a dummy - there seems to be no subject in his example.

Comment: @StoneyB Actually, in my Italian example there is a subject: _trovare il colpevole_. Then, it is also true that in Italian a personal pronoun used as subject of a sentence is not obbligatory, and using it could give a different meaning to the sentence. In some cases, when in English _it_ is used as subject in Italian the subject is different: When I ring a door's bell, and who is inside the house wants to know who is at the door, in Italian I reply with _sono io_ (litterally, "[I] am me") which is different from _è me_. I would say _è me che cerci_ ("it's me who you are looking for"), though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  Thanks for the correction. Your language does not require the subject in first position, though? - as English does. For instance, would a word-for-word translation of your last sentence be *is me whom [you] seek*?

Comment: @StoneyB I have 3 different ways for saying "I am guilty": _io sono il colpevole_, _sono io il colpevole_, and _il colpevole sono io_. Yes, the subject could not be in first position, but I could not say _ama Luigi Veronica_ for "Luigi loves Veronica." (Let's forget for a moment "Ama Luigi, Veronica?" which could be used for "Does Veronica love Luigi?") That would be a word-for-word translation, you are correct. (_È_ is the translation for _is_, when used for the third person singular.)